# Check if 2 or more items in array are the same - Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am currently making an application where I need to check if 2 or more items in an array are the same.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim aNumbers = New Short() {iNumOne, iNumTwo, iNumThree}
```

How would I check if 2 or more variables are the same in the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will tell you if there are duplicates present

```
    Dim dups As Boolean = Not aNumbers.Distinct.Count.Equals(aNumbers.Length)
    If dups Then
        'there are duplicates
    Else
        'no duplicates
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

**Using LINQ**

```
Dim aNumbers_filtered = From number In aNumbers _
                    Group number By Key = number Into Group _
                    Where Group.Count() > 1
                    Select Number = Key, NumberCount = Group.Count()
```